# No internet / Can't install plugins on OctoPrint

Tags: octoprint

I have installed OctoPi on my Raspberry Pi 3b+, that is connected to a mks gen l v1.0 motherboard for my 3D printer (Ender 3 Pro). When I open my OctoPrint into a browser I can use it, but I wanted to install some plugins. First time I had an error that said my server was offline, after connecting my Raspberry to Wifi and setting up a static ip-address, I've connected my Raspberry to my main board, after that it said the status of OctoPrint was operational, so I expected it will work..

Sadly, it says that my installation doesn't have internet, so I still couldn't install plugins. I see that in the "connectivity check" my host is 8.8.8.8 and my port 53; I've pressed on test and there it said "server is unreachable".

What am I supposed to do?

Comment: You would have better luck getting this answered over at [3D Printing](https://3dprinting.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score -2):

Try repowering your internet, if that does not work, try installing plugins from zip files